# Can you display all information from a class using a loop in Java

Tags: java

I am wondering if there is a way to use a loop to display class information.

For example, if I have multiple instance created like,

```
Specimen a = new Specimen("1", "2", "3");
Specimen b = new Specimen("4", "5", "6");
```

and a toString method which would display my information in the desired way; is there any possible way to use a loop or while to print a.toString() and b.toString() and so on (c,d,e,f,g, etc) without having to continuously type a.toString(), b.toString, etc.

This is currently what my main method looks like

```
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Specimen SF11 = new Specimen("SF11", "Starfish", 10, 20 );
        System.out.println(SF11.toString());
        Specimen SU12 = new Specimen("SU12", "Sea Urchin", 12, 25);
        System.out.println(SU12.toString());
        SF11.setsCount(16); SF11.setsName("Blue Starfish"); SF11.setsTank(22);
        System.out.print(SF11.toString() + "\n" + SU12.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129326/discussion-on-question-by-kylian-murphy-can-you-display-all-information-from-a-c).